# How to plot the equalized histogram of an image with Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib

So this is my code. The variable img is the original image. The variable eq is the equalized image.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread, imshow, show, subplot, title, get_cmap, hist
from skimage.exposure import equalize_hist


img = imread('images/city.tif')
eq = equalize_hist(img)

subplot(221); imshow(img, cmap=get_cmap('gray')); title('Original')
subplot(222); hist(img.flatten(), 256, range=(0,256)); title('Histogram of      origianl')
subplot(223); imshow(eq, cmap=get_cmap('gray'));  title('Histogram Equalized')
subplot(224); hist(eq.flatten(), 256, range=(0,256));

show()
```

Now when I run, the code, I get the histogram of the original just fine. But the histogram of the equalized is incorrect. This is all of my output

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?!?!

EDIT: The builtin matlab commands from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31305100/1320237) works fine for the particular image

[image]

Comment: Oh, you forgot a `=` in the second `hist()`  call. There is `range(0, 256)` instead of `range=(0, 256)`

Comment: I've fixed it, thank you. That just outputs a 'too many values to unpack'. It doesn't affect the problem with histogram

Comment: Maybe the values are only between 0 and 1.

Comment: I don't think so. I used the same algorithm with many gray scale images, and the output does not change.

Comment: I'd check out the suggestion from @User, it fits the symptoms perfectly. The output values from `equalize_hist` appear to be floating point numbers in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's converting the image from `uint8` format (integer values between 0 and 255 inclusive) to a `float32` or `float64` format (floating point values between 0 and 1 inclusive).  Try `eq = np.asarray(equalize_hist(img) * 255, dtype='uint8')`.